# Search for a bundle by name in Apache Felix gogo shell

Tags: java, liferay, osgi, osgi-bundle, liferay-7

I'd like to search for a bundle by name in OSGI. Right now when I do

```
telnet localhost 11311 

lb
```

Then it gives me a list of all bundles registered with the Liferay framework. Like this:

```
 502|Active     |   10|Liferay Layout Taglib (2.0.8)
 503|Active     |   10|Liferay Layout Type Controller Control Panel (2.0.2)
 504|Active     |   10|Liferay Layout Type Controller Full Page Application 
 (2.0.3)
 505|Active     |   10|Liferay Layout Type Controller Node (2.0.2)
 ..............................<something like this>
```

I had to scroll all the way from top to bottom (sometimes my bundles are shown all the way top). Is there a way to search a bundle by name on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. For example:

```
lb Layout
```

or

```
lb | grep "Layout Type"
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the first line <lb Layout> by now, but the second one: 
<lb | grep "Layout Type"> surely helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
la -s | grep "<bundle symbolic name>"
```